# fancyhdr: How to start header at the very left margin of paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I am trying to produce a document with a header that consists of a rectangle rounded on one side that begins at the very left of the paper width.

I fail at letting the rectangle begin outside of the width of the text. How can I include this in my fancyhdr-setup? And in addition, but of less priority, could the white text in the blue rounded rectangle begin at textwidth, i.e. not on the outmost left side? (That is, after the first issue has been addressed).

Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{004173}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.misc}

%headers and footers

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}


\fancyhead{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2mm, every node/.style={rounded rectangle, minimum size = 6mm,draw=myblue,fill=myblue, text = white, font=\small}, very thick]
\node (author) [rounded rectangle west arc=none, align = left] {One author et al. \\
An here is an unnecessarily long title with many, many words};
\node (report) [rounded rectangle, align = left, right= of author] {Our Report \\ 1/2017};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\fancyfoot{}
\rfoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[pagina/.style={circle, minimum size = 6mm, draw= myblue, fill = myblue, text = white}]
\node (pagerino) [pagina] {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}}





\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Which yields this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `overlay` and then position the picture with respect to the page corners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The left margin (with `oneside`) is `\oddsidemargin` plus one inch; you can pass such dimension to `\fancyheadoffset`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{004173}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.misc}

%headers and footers

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\fancyhf{} % clear header and footer
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm,
    every node/.style={
      rounded rectangle,
      minimum size = 6mm,
      draw=myblue,
      fill=myblue,
      text = white,
      font=\small,
    },
    very thick,
  ]
  \node (author) [rounded rectangle west arc=none, align = left] {%
    One author et al. \\
    An here is an unnecessarily long title with many, many words%
  };
  \node (report) [rounded rectangle, align = left, right= of author] {%
    Our Report \\ 1/2017%
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    pagina/.style={
      circle,
      minimum size = 6mm,
      draw= myblue,
      fill = myblue,
      text = white,
    },
  ]
  \node (pagerino) [pagina] {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyheadoffset[L]{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{34pt}% value suggested by fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]